# creating a table in java using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a table in java using arrays, this is the code i have done so far:

```
int[ ][ ] aryNumbers = new int[6][5];

aryNumbers[0][0] = 10;
aryNumbers[0][1] = 12;
aryNumbers[0][2] = 43;
aryNumbers[0][3] = 11;
aryNumbers[0][4] = 22;

aryNumbers[1][0] = 20;
aryNumbers[1][1] = 45;
aryNumbers[1][2] = 56;
aryNumbers[1][3] = 1;
aryNumbers[1][4] = 33;

aryNumbers[2][0] = 30;
aryNumbers[2][1] = 67;
aryNumbers[2][2] = 32;
aryNumbers[2][3] = 14;
aryNumbers[2][4] = 44;

aryNumbers[3][0] = 40;
aryNumbers[3][1] = 12;
aryNumbers[3][2] = 87;
aryNumbers[3][3] = 14;
aryNumbers[3][4] = 55;

aryNumbers[4][0] = 50;
aryNumbers[4][1] = 86;
aryNumbers[4][2] = 66;
aryNumbers[4][3] = 13;
aryNumbers[4][4] = 66;

aryNumbers[5][0] = 60;
aryNumbers[5][1] = 53;
aryNumbers[5][2] = 44;
aryNumbers[5][3] = 12;
aryNumbers[5][4] = 11;

int rows = 6;
int columns = 5;

int i, j;

for (i=0; i < rows ; i++) {
    for (j=0; j < columns ; j++) {
       System.out.print( aryNumbers[ i ][ j ] + " " );
    }

    System.out.println( "" );
}
```

It prints it out in rows and columns which I want it to do, but I want to add a heading/label to every row and column, to name it like a table. How can I do this?

Comment: add your row name to the outer loop and your column name to the inner loop

Comment: Could you implement the solution in my code if you could?

Comment: Might have to wait a while if you don't mind, just going out for a jog ☺.

Answer (score 0):

You learn by trying.

```
/* TODO: Print out column heading here */

for (i=0; i < rows ; i++) {

    /* TODO: Print out i-th row label here */

    for (j=0; j < columns ; j++) {
        System.out.print( aryNumbers[ i ][ j ] + " " );
    }

    System.out.println( "" );
}
```

Fill in the TODO's.

Comment: i want to name every column and every row something different?

Comment: Ok.  Then use `System.out.print("something different");` for the i-th row TODO, and create a loop around a `System.out.print("something different");` statement for the column heading TODO, and every column and every row will be named "something different".  Or perhaps that's not what you wanted, and perhaps you need to clarify your question a bit.

Comment: No i meant each column and row called something different e.g Hammer , Screwdrivers etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++){
  System.out.print("COLUMN LABEL ");
  if(x == columns - 1){
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
}
for (i=0; i < rows ; i++) {
        for (j=0; j < columns ; j++) {
           System.out.print( aryNumbers[ i ][ j ] + " " );
        }

   System.out.println( "ROW LABEL " );
}
```

Comment: i want each row to have a different name and each row having a different name

Comment: Those were simply examples.  If you want to dynamically name your rows and columns.  Create an array of columnlabels that is the same size as the number of columns you have.  Then in that for loops do `System.out.print(columnLabels[i]);`.  Do the same for rowLabels.